# Nested for loop with multiple operations using List Comprehension

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

Just understanding List Comprehensions, as in a recent interview the tech guy asked me this question and being a self learner I answered lambda which is NOT list comprehension.

let say we have a time series data "Shiller", http://us.spindices.com/indices/real-estate/sp-corelogic-case-shiller-us-national-home-price-nsa-index

I calculated aic/bic using following loop:

```
shiller = [please use some random data or use the link above]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

def aicbic(shiller):
  arimaijk = []
  aicijk = []
  bicijk = []
  index = []
  for i in range(1,3):
      for j in range(1,2):
          for k in range(0,5):
              arimaijk.append(sm.tsa.ARIMA(shiller,(i,j,k)).fit())
              index.append([i,j,k])
              aicijk.append(arimaijk[k].aic)            
              bicijk.append(arimaijk[k].bic)
  return aicijk, bicijk

aicbic(shiller)
Out[9]: 
([-235.77314152121426,-233.9375761653174,-233.3841011331017,-241.65994870973782,-240.2975620564456,-235.77314152121426,-233.9375761653174,-233.3841011331017,-241.65994870973782,-240.2975620564456],
 [-227.98778197081049,-223.55709676477906,-220.40850188242874,-226.08922960893028,-222.13172310550345,-227.98778197081049,-223.55709676477906,-220.40850188242874,-226.08922960893028,-222.13172310550345])
```

Now, I want this result using List Comprehension, so I wrote following lines, which are returning error:

```
def aicbic(data):    
  arimaijk = []
  aicijk = []
  bicijk = []
  index = []
  [(sm.tsa.ARIMA(data,(i,j,k)).fit(),index.append([i,j,k]),\
  aicijk.append(arimaijk[k].aic),bicijk.append(arimaijk[k].bic)) \
  for i in range(1,3) for j in range(1,2) for k in range(0,5)]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: List comprehension will build only one list at a time.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, any alternative for this operation?

Comment: You can use list comprehensions here.  You will just need to cut it up a bit differently.  And if you had constructed a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, I would have done it for you.  And likely so would have the other people who voted to close this question.

Comment: Added some data and libraries, if you mean that for  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: To get the best help here, we want to be able to cut and paste right from the post into an editor, and then run the code.  With verifiable results. Then we can change the code and make sure the results are still good. If we know something, it is generally the tools, not *your* problem domain.  So, you just pasted some data named `shiller`, but your code does not reference it.  Also there are no expected results.

Comment: OK, done. Sorry for the trouble! I was not sure if I can reproduce S&P data here, but anyway I did it partially. I will take it down in sometime.

Comment: 1) use fake data.  It should not matter for the example.  2) have you cut and paste from this post and run it?  It does not run.  Sigh....

Comment: I think its OK for now to use the data as its freely available. It's not full. I did copy paste now and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function recast using itertools and list comprehensions:

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it

def aicbic(shiller):
    loop = list(it.product(range(1, 3), range(1, 2), range(0, 5)))
    arimaijk = [sm.tsa.ARIMA(shiller, (i, j, k)).fit() for i, j, k in loop]
    aicijk = [arimaijk[k].aic for i, j, k in loop]
    bicijk = [arimaijk[k].bic for i, j, k in loop]
    return aicijk, bicijk
```

**Test Code:**

```
result = aicbic(shiller)

import numpy as np
assert np.all(np.isclose(result, (
    [-235.77314152121426, -233.9375761653174, -233.3841011331017,
     -241.65994870973782, -240.2975620564456, -235.77314152121426,
     -233.9375761653174, -233.3841011331017, -241.65994870973782,
     -240.2975620564456],
    [-227.98778197081049, -223.55709676477906, -220.40850188242874,
     -226.08922960893028, -222.13172310550345, -227.98778197081049,
     -223.55709676477906, -220.40850188242874, -226.08922960893028,
     -222.13172310550345]
)))
```

**Note:**

You likely have a bug of some sort, as `aicijk` and `bicijk` depend only on `k`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

The error does not relate to list comprehenstion itself:

```
[(sm.tsa.ARIMA(data,(i,j,k)).fit(),index.append([i,j,k]),\
  aicijk.append(arimaijk[k].aic),bicijk.append(arimaijk[k].bic)) \
  for i in range(1,3) for j in range(1,2) for k in range(0,5)]
```

The error `IndexError: list index out of range` is raised because you want to access `arimaijk[k]` while `arimaijk` is an empty list (the first line of `aicbic(data)` function is `arimaijk=[]`).

Comment: This does not address the problem.  List comprehensions are intended to construct a list.  This code is using a side effect of the list comprehension to append to two lists and thus create the list inside of a list comprehension.  In this case a for loop would be a better solution.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects#5753614

Comment: I just clarified what is the reason for the `IndexError`. Thank you anyway, Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hossein, I guess now I know how to use List Comprehensions!

```
def aicbic(data):
  arimaijk = []
  aicijk = []
  bicijk = []
  index = []
  [(arimaijk.append(sm.tsa.ARIMA(data,(i,j,k)).fit()),index.append([i,j,k]),\
  aicijk.append(arimaijk[k].aic),bicijk.append(arimaijk[k].bic)) \
  for i in range(1,3) for j in range(1,2) for k in range(0,5)]
  return aicijk, bicijk


result = aicbic(shiller)
```

Comment: What?  No.  You are entirely missing the point....  If your list comprehension solution is given on an interview you will not get the job.  For your sake, please study what I wrote.

Comment: Hi Stephen, this is only the part of the code where I wanted to understand how can I reimplement it using List Comprehension. You're right about the code that it depends only on k. I need to think another code for p in ARIMA(p,1,q) i.e. 'i'. If you mean that. Also, this question was not on interview. The tech guy only asked explain 'List Comprehension' and answered 'Lambda'. But apparently its not correct.

Comment: Read my response to Hossein's answer.  To think that his answer is correct will confuse you going forward.

Comment: OK. It doesn't make sense to use 'append' within List Comprehension. You're absolutely correct. Thanks Stephen for defending your point.

Comment: In my answer, I just clarified what is the reason for `IndexError`. About the list comprehension, I agree with Stephen that when you don't want to explicitly use the output of a list comprehension, you should avoid using the list comprehension.